# Unable to deploy app using Device Chooser after upgrading Android Studio to 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, samsung-mobile, watch

This morning I upgraded the Android Studio from 1.3.[something] to 1.4.
After the upgrade, when I runned the app at the bottom of the Device Chooser dialog there is a message in red "The selected device is incompatible." and the OK button is disabled.

I have multiple devices here with different android versions. On some of them which are having android 5.0+ installed there was OK text in the "Compatible" column in the Choose a running device list. After the upgrade, all are "incompatible".

Can someone please advice what to do?
Should I make a fresh installation of the older Android Studio (1.3) and continue to work?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I can really say Android Studio is notoriously known for wasting a lot of developers time. Imagine if you are in an actual workplace where time is pretty much essential, you cannot deliver since you are wasting time tinkering with things like these. This is pretty annoying.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After struggling for some time, i have found a workaround:
Instead of using the Device Chooser dialog, you have to deploy it directly.
Steps to fix the issue:

1. Open the Run/Debug configurations dialog.
2. Select your app configuration from the tree on the left.
3. In the General tab, locate the Target Device group box and select the USB Device radio button.

When you run the app it will not display the Device Chooser dialog, it will deploy the app directly on the connected android device directly.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks so much, this approach works, +1.  I still don't understand the difference between specifying USB device and using Device Chooser?

Comment: The difference is that when you have the USB device option selected, then the Android Studio directly deploys the app on the connected USB device without displaying the Device Chooser dialog.

Comment: OK thanks.  Then there should be only one USB device attached, right?

Comment: When I was using this workaround, I used only one device attached.. so I'm not sure if this works with multiple devices attached... theoretically it should.

Answer (score 5):

For those who still got the error when running the Mobile app, it's an issue with Android Studio 1.4.

```
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187665
```

Apparently, the issue is this line:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" android:required="false"/>
```

Android studio seems to be ignoring the `android:required="false"` part. Hopefully, it'll be fixed in subsequent updates.

I fixed the issue temporarily by invalidating cache and restarting Android Studio (Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate Cache and Restart). However, if this doesn't work, then you can try by bypassing the dialog in your run configurations and choosing either the device directly or emulator.

Comment: I have reported the issue on their issue tracking site: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=188746

As they said, the fix will be available at version 1.4.1 and 1.5.